# Jquery daterange picker callback function not calling

Tags: jquery, daterangepicker

I have dynamic jquery daterange picker , I want to find the event when date range selected (textbox changed, picker close)

I have following code

```
$('input[id=date-ranged]').dateRangePicker(
    {
        singleMonth: true,
        showShortcuts: false,
        showTopbar: false
    }, function (start, end) { alert('hello'); });
```

but the callback function is not firing.

Any help highly appreciated

Thanks

Comment: Have you put this code in a piece of code that is executed only after the DOM has finished loading?

Answer (score 0):

> Try init picker after DOM has finished loading.

```
$(function() {
    $('input[id=date-ranged]').dateRangePicker({
        singleMonth: true,
        showShortcuts: false,
        showTopbar: false
    }, function (start, end) { 
        alert('hello'); 
    });
});
```